# android how to cancel showing ad when Back Button Pressed .?

Tags: android

How to stop showing admob ad when *back button* pressed , I am managing the issue by leaving empty `setAdUnitId` and it works but I would like to have any other solution if possible

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
                    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("");
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

                    mWebView.goBack();

                    initAds();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40858316/2196176).

Answer (score 0):

When you have defined your `adView` in the layout like this:

```
 final AdView adViewLayout = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView1);
```

You might try to just change the visibility of that part of the layout:

```
 adViewLayout.setEnabled(false);
 adViewLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```